# How to get your qsub script information that you submitted before?

Tags: gridengine

Since qstat only shows limited information, see the following as an example. But I want to know the details of a job `AAA` (say it was submitted by `qsub sample`, this sample script I guess must be stored by the SGE system somewhere... right?). How can I later view this `sample` file by its name or job-ID? If this is impossible, that's fine, but is there **any SGE log files or history records that I can go and check the historical scripts I have submitted?** Thanks a lot.

Or I can put it in another way: Does SGE store my qsub scripts? If yes, where does it store them?

```
$ qstat -help
UGE 8.1.4

$ qstat -u myusername
job-ID  prior   name       user         state submit/start at     queue                          jclass                         slots ja-task-ID 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123456 5.87507 AAA        aaaaa        r     01/01/2011 00:11:43 long@aaaaaaaaa.aaa.aa.edu                                        24
```

Comment: Are you the administrator for SGE?

Comment: No. Why don't you tell us the answers for both? So that if I can't do it, I can talk to the guy in charge of this. :)

Comment: Because this is the Q&A site for professional system administrators.  Check out http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

qstat -j 123456

gives detailed information about the job, including the script location.  if allowed you could ssh to aaaaaaaaa.aaa.aa.edu and examine the file.

qacct -j 123456 
may show you info on runtime, memory and throughput for historical jobs. if accounting is on and it's set up to find the file.  on our setup we have to unpack the accounting file and call it with -f unpacked.file also